# Creating top menu items and right login menu

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to create top menu items and login text aligned to the right?

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
#header {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#header ol {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header li {
    position: relative;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#login_details {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">

<ol>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
</ol>

<div id="login_details">
dd
</div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to do this at the moment but the text in **login_details** isn't properly aligning to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/KqqyY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `login_details` div before the list:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="login_details">dd</div>
    <ol>
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
        <li>Page 4</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And change your CSS to include the `line-height: 27px;` on your login_details div:

```
#login_details {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 27px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KqqyY/1/)**

Since you floated the login details box to the right, it needs to come before the list in order to sit on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `text-align` property and make the `ol` `float:left`. I've also added some more stuff:

```
#login_details {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

#header ol {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#header {
    height: 25px;
    // Get rid of the 100% width to make it fit on screen
    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `#header` container has a with of 100%, and after that you add padding to it causing it to grow larger than 100%, you could solve this with `box-sizing:border-box`

```
#header {
    height:45px; /* The original 25px plus the paddings from the top and bottom */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KqqyY/2/**